# C# to VBNET conversion issue

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters

I have some C# code to add to an existing VB.net project.
The C# class is designed as a html parser

Have initally used an online converter and was able to get most of the class working, but the piece below is still not functioning. Unfortunately I lack in the knowledge to fix this.

I am posting the whole piece, but if someone can clarify the first couple of lines, I assume that would be enough. 
AttributeNameValuePair is a separate class that holds the attribute.

Further down some inline functions are used, would appreciate an example of that aswell. Or would it be easier to make these as separate functions and leave only a reference inside?

Thanks beforehand for any assistance.

```
            private readonly Dictionary<string, Action<DocumentModel, IEnumerable<AttributeNameValuePair>>> commandsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action<DocumentModel, IEnumerable<AttributeNameValuePair>>>()
    {
        { "b", new Action<DocumentModel, IEnumerable<AttributeNameValuePair>>((doc, args) => GetLastRun(doc).CharacterFormat.Bold = true) },
        { "i", new Action<DocumentModel, IEnumerable<AttributeNameValuePair>>((doc, args) => GetLastRun(doc).CharacterFormat.Italic = true) },
        { "u", new Action<DocumentModel, IEnumerable<AttributeNameValuePair>>((doc, args) => GetLastRun(doc).CharacterFormat.UnderlineStyle = UnderlineType.Single) },
        { "strike", new Action<DocumentModel, IEnumerable<AttributeNameValuePair>>((doc, args) => GetLastRun(doc).CharacterFormat.Strikethrough = true) },
        { "sub", new Action<DocumentModel, IEnumerable<AttributeNameValuePair>>((doc, args) => GetLastRun(doc).CharacterFormat.Subscript = true) },
        { "sup", new Action<DocumentModel, IEnumerable<AttributeNameValuePair>>((doc, args) => GetLastRun(doc).CharacterFormat.Superscript = true) },
        { "div", new Action<DocumentModel, IEnumerable<AttributeNameValuePair>>((doc, args) => 
            {
              foreach(var arg in args)
              {
                  if(arg.AttributeName == "align")
                  {
                      HorizontalAlignment align;
                      switch(arg.AttributeValue)
                      {
                          case "center":
                              align = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                              break;
                          case "right":
                              align = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                              break;
                          case "justify":
                              align = HorizontalAlignment.Justify;
                              break;
                          default:
                              align = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                              break;
                      }
                  }
              }
            })},
        { "br", new Action<DocumentModel, IEnumerable<AttributeNameValuePair>>((doc, args) => doc.Sections[0].Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(doc))) },
        {  "span",  new Action<DocumentModel, IEnumerable<AttributeNameValuePair>>((doc, args) => {})},
        { "font", new Action<DocumentModel, IEnumerable<AttributeNameValuePair>>((doc, args) => 
            {
                foreach(AttributeNameValuePair arg in args)
                {
                    int? size = null;
                    string fontName = null;

                    // Some dummy values.
                    if (arg.AttributeName == "size")
                        size = 10 + 3 * int.Parse(arg.AttributeValue);
                    else if (arg.AttributeName == "face")
                        fontName = arg.AttributeValue.Split(',').First();

                    var lastFormat = GetLastRun(doc).CharacterFormat;
                    if (size.HasValue)
                        lastFormat.Size = size.Value;

                    if (fontName != null)
                        lastFormat.FontName = fontName;
                }
            })},
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of vb.net is this?  Lambda expressions work a bit differently in each of them.  Multiline lambda is only supported in VS2010+.  For VS2008 you usually end up having to turn anonymous methods into real methods and reference them via `AddressOf`.  Automatic translation, I've noticed, generally seems to fail when converting anonymous/lambda type expressions from C#->VB.

In any case, anonymous method syntax in VB is a bit clumsier and different enough, compared to C#, to be confusing. For the single line methods you would do something like this (I'm using simple types for clarity) :

```
Private cmdDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Action(Of Integer, String))

'adding items'
cmdDictionary.Add("div", New Action(Of Integer, String) _
      (Sub(x As Integer, y As String) Console.WriteLine(y & ":" & CStr(x))))

'then to access the dictionary'
cmdDictionary.Item("div")(42, "foobar")
```

For multiline (in vs2010) the pattern looks like:

```
cmdDictionary.Add("div", New Action(Of Integer, String) _
                        (Sub(x As Integer, y As String)
                             x = 2 * x
                             Console.WriteLine(y & ":" & CStr(x))
                         End Sub))
```

Comment: @pophatis added some examples, then

Comment: Thanks J I was able to step over that hurdle, and get further. Was able to fix some other issues rightaway, just happy to get some coding done and progress. Therefor didnot get around to thank you rightaway, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can translate this C# code 1:1 to VB.Net.

In this example I added only `b` and `div`, but it should be enough to guide you:

```
Private Readonly commandsDictionary As Dictionary(Of string, Action(Of DocumentModel, IEnumerable(Of AttributeNameValuePair))) = 
new Dictionary(Of string, Action(Of DocumentModel, IEnumerable(Of AttributeNameValuePair)))() From 
{
    { "b", new Action(Of DocumentModel, IEnumerable(Of AttributeNameValuePair)) (Sub(doc, args) GetLastRun(doc).CharacterFormat.Bold = true) },
    { "div", new Action(Of DocumentModel, IEnumerable(Of AttributeNameValuePair))(Sub(doc, args)  
          For Each arg in args
              if arg.AttributeName = "align" Then
                  Dim align as HorizontalAlignment
                  Select arg.AttributeValue
                      case "center":
                          align = HorizontalAlignment.Center
                      case "right":
                          align = HorizontalAlignment.Right
                      case "justify":
                          align = HorizontalAlignment.Justify
                      case else:
                          align = HorizontalAlignment.Left
                  end select
              end if
          Next
    End Sub)}}
}
```

You maybe want to create a type alias for `Action(Of DocumentModel, IEnumerable(Of AttributeNameValuePair))`, as it would greatly improve readability.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Steak tried a couple of notations, but finally ended up using your example, since this fits very nicely. Appreciate you taking the time. Do feel I need to brush up on my coding skills in VB but probably also get a basic grasp for C#. Looking for info online I tend to get lost when trying to combine different solutions for my own, especially when most are written in C#.